# How to decrypt in node js that is sent from react by encrypting? ()

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption

I want to encrypt all my request from the client end and decrypt it in backend side. I am useing Crypto-Js in the react for the encryption. I am getting the encrypted request when i console it as req.body . But how can I decrypt it in my node js side? I am getting error with crypto in node js side. This is what I have tried so far:

React.js

```
transformRequest: [
    (data, headers) => {
      
      var ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data), '&CzHaI!ux0C1av5#fwD$4^lAN%haKqo0').toString();
      console.log(ciphertext);
      return ciphertext;
    },
    ...axios.defaults.transformRequest,
  ],
```

Nodejs:(created a middlewire)

```
let decryptionService = function(req, res, next) {
let decryptionData = decryptMessage(req.body)

console.log(decryptionData);
next();
}
```

**in the decryp.js file:**

```
function decryptMessage(msg){

// secret key generate 32 bytes of random data
const Securitykey = "&CzHaI!ux0C1av5#fwD$4^lAN%haKqo0";



const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, Securitykey, initVector);

console.log("Decrypted decipher: " + JSON.stringify(decipher));


let decryptedData = decipher.update(msg, "hex", "utf-8");

console.log("Decrypted decryptedData: " + decryptedData);


decryptedData += decipher.final("utf8");

console.log("Decrypted message: " + decryptedData);

return decryptedData;
}
```

Comment: why not use Crypto-JS in node - that way you're guaranteed there will be no hidden "gotchas" - `I am getting error` ... exactly what is the error -  `crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, Securitykey, initVector)` ... what are the values of `algorithm` and `initvector`

Comment: "I want to encrypt all my request from the client end and decrypt it in backend side." Then use HTTPS and don't roll your own encryption with a static key.

Comment: @AKX I will use https later. but at this moment I need this to be done in http.

Comment: @ManasS.Roy Please understand that this scheme has no actual security, so I don't see a point implementing it.

Comment: To be compatible with the NodeJS code, pass in the CryptoJS code key and IV as `WordArray` (s. the [CryptoJS doc](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#custom-key-and-iv)). For this, choose the appropriate encoder for both (e.g. `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8` for the key). Also, the appropriate algorithm (`aes-256-cbc`) and input encoding (`base64`) must be set in the NodeJS code.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. It works for me

```
var bytes  = crypto.AES.decrypt(msg, Securitykey);
var decryptedData = JSON.parse(bytes.toString(crypto.enc.Utf8));
```